# Dudas al cargar año y mes actuales

Tags: java, android

Lo que pretendo es que el presente formulario me cargue el año y el mes actual y llevarlos a las distintas cajas de texto que se poseen. Este es mi código que utilizo actualmente:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Frmvaloruf extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText et_busqueda, et_filas, et_año, et_mes, et_valor, et_activo, colFilas, colAño, colMes, colFecha, colValor;
TableLayout tbldatos;
private String[]header={"N° Filas","Año","Mes","Fecha","Valor U.F"};
private ArrayList<String[]> rows=new ArrayList<>();
private TableDynamic tableDynamic;
private String mes;
RequestQueue requestQueue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_frmvaloruf);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    et_busqueda = findViewById(R.id.txtbusqueda7);
    et_filas = findViewById(R.id.txtitem2);
    et_año = findViewById(R.id.txtaño);
    et_mes = findViewById(R.id.txtmes);
    et_valor = findViewById(R.id.txtuf);
    et_activo = findViewById(R.id.txtactivo7);
    tbldatos = findViewById(R.id.tbldatos);

    tableDynamic = new TableDynamic(tbldatos, getApplicationContext());
    tableDynamic.addHeader(header);
    tableDynamic.addData(getClients());
    tableDynamic.backgroundHeader(Color.BLUE);
    tableDynamic.backgroundData(Color.RED, Color.YELLOW);
    tableDynamic.lineColor(Color.BLACK);
    tableDynamic.textColorData(Color.WHITE);
    tableDynamic.textColorHeader(Color.MAGENTA);
    Calendar cal= Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar c1= Calendar.getInstance();
    int year= cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    et_año.setText(year);
    String MES[] = {"Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"};
    mes = MES[c1.get(Calendar.MONTH)];
    et_mes.setText(mes);
    mostrardatos();
}

private ArrayList<String[]> getClients(){

    return rows;
}

public void datos (){
    String[]item = new String[]{et_filas.getText().toString(),et_año.getText().toString(),et_mes.getText().toString(),et_valor.getText().toString()};
    tableDynamic.addItems(item);
}

public void mostrardatos (){
    String url = "http://192.168.1.96/oficina/buscar_uf.php";
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("data");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    LayoutInflater reg1 = getLayoutInflater();
                    View registro = reg1.inflate(R.layout.tabla2,null, false);
                    colFilas=registro.findViewById(R.id.colFilas);
                    colAño=registro.findViewById(R.id.colAño);
                    colMes=registro.findViewById(R.id.colMes);
                    colFecha=registro.findViewById(R.id.colFecha);
                    colValor=registro.findViewById(R.id.colValor);
                    colFilas.setText(jsonObject.getString("N_Filas"));
                    colAño.setText(jsonObject.getString("Año_UF"));
                    colMes.setText(jsonObject.getString("Mes_UF"));
                    colFecha.setText(jsonObject.getString("Dia_UF"));
                    colValor.setText(jsonObject.getString("Valor_UF"));
                    tbldatos.addView(registro);
                    int j = 1;
                    int a = 1;
                    for (int x = 0; x <= tbldatos.getChildCount(); x++) {
                        int suma = x + j;
                        int suma1 = suma - a;
                        et_filas.setText("" + suma1);
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

No poseo ningún error al momento de ejecutarlo, pero al momento de hacer correr el programa pasando anteriormente por la opción del menú, me dirige al formulario presente y me envía el mensaje del Toast, pero me bota automáticamente: es decir, se corta. Dejo en comentario lo concerniente lo del año y el mes y no hay problema, vuelvo correr el programa y selecciono la opción del menú y carga el formulario sin problema. No sé a que se deba tal error.

Comment: Pon un título más descriptivo: _duda con..._ no nos da pistas del problema puntual que estás teniendo. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.